# Implicit function Taylor series error bound

Tags: implicit-differentiation

Given the implicit curve
$$x^4y^5+x^2y^3+y+x-1=0$$
I have found the Taylor polynomial around $x=0$ of third order to be
$$p(x)=1-x-x^2+3x^3.$$
My objective now is to find an error bound for the approximation for $y(0.1)$ given by $p(0.1)=0.893$. Of course I could attempt to find the supremum of the 4th derivative of $y$ but this turns out to be way too complicated. Is there any alternative way to find such error bound?

Comment: One approach: You can put $y=p+\epsilon$ in the equation. You get a polynomial in $\epsilon$ with coefficients in $x$. There are [many bounds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Properties_of_polynomial_roots#Bounds_on_(complex)_polynomial_roots) for the roots of a polinomial in terms of the coefficients. That would give you a bound for $\epsilon$ depending on $x$. Finally, put $x=0.1$ in the bound.

Comment: Since the convergence radius of your power series is the distance from $0$ to the closest singularity at $x=-0.057419 - 0.405110 i $, i.e. about $0.41$, I wouldn't expect too much.